# How to change Bootstrap Datatable head column width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the Bootstrap DataTable head columns width.
I tried multiple solution bit its not working.

```html
<div class="frame" style="height: 750px; overflow: auto; padding: 7px 20px 20px 20px; ">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
 <tr>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th> Last Name</th>
  <th>Organization Name</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  <th>Country</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I tried to change the second column width like that but dint work

```
<th style="width: 60px"> Last Name</th>
```

how do i change the width of particular column.
please help

Answer (score 0):

Set "bAutoWidth" property of the datatable to false while initializing the datatable and set the width of the column as you are doing above.